# How to use `pylint` on code supporting multiple Python versions?

Tags: python, pylint, error-suppression

Since `hashlib.file_digest` was introduced only in Python 3.11, I use a fallback to the previous code:

```py
if sys.version_info < (3, 11):
    digest = hashlib.sha256()
    digest.update(file.read())
else:
    digest = hashlib.file_digest(file, hashlib.sha256)
```

Running `pylint` on Python 3.10 on this file, I get the following error:

> `Module 'hashlib' has no 'file_digest' member (no-member)`

I can add `# pylint: disable=no-member` to the bottom branch of the code, but then I will get

> `Useless suppression of 'no-member' (useless-suppression)`

when `pylint` is run in Python 3.11.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a setup where you globally (through a configuration file or a command line option) disable the `useless-suppression` warning when running `pylint` with 3.11. (This would be very specific for this type of issue, and may not work for another type of issue.)

Comment: @9769953 I get your point. But I did enable `useless-suppression` for a reason, after all :)